# How to play multiple swf files continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash

I have developed web page with HTML.I am trying to play multiple .swf files (3 or 4 files) continuously which are in a div tag..

```
<div class="slider_body">
<embed src="Presentations.swf" width="1162" height="430px" style="position:relative; left:55px;>
<embed src="services.swf" width="1162" height="430px" style="position:relative; left:55px;>

</div>
```

how can I achieve this?

Comment: continuously in the sense, you need to play one after another?

Comment: yes,after completion of 1st file,I want to play next one

Comment: It is not possible to achieve this with javascript alone. You need to have a callback from each swf that it has finished its play and you need to have start play method in each swf which should be accessible through javascript. Then you need to call play method of your next swf once  you get play finished callback from previous swf. Check [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to easily embed swf with additional methods, [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to use JS with flash.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the ["**loop**" parameter](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html#optional) and Object tag, best practice would involve using an [SWFObject](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed your swf file for browser compatibility.

```
<param name="loop" value="true">
```

Although the [loop parameter does not work on Flex applications](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=wrapper_14.html#166805).